# How to prove $B_n$ is a cauchy sequence given $|B_n - B_{n-1}| < \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

How do I prove $B_n$ is a Cauchy sequence given
$$|B_n - B_{n-1}| < \frac{1}{n!}$$
I can prove that that the above approaches $0$ as $n$ becomes large since $n! > 2^n$ and thus setting $N = \log_2\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ but don't know how to relate it to the definition of a Cauchy sequence:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m> N$ $\Rightarrow |B_n - B_m| ≤ \epsilon$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $m>n\geq 1$ then
$$|B_m - B_{n}| \leq |B_m - B_{m-1}| +\dots+|B_{n+1} - B_{n}| <\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{k!}\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}<\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$
where $2^{k-1}\leq k!$ for $k\geq 2$. 
Can you evaluate the last (geometric) series and finish the job?

Comment: I understand the logic behind it but I'm unsure of how to get from there to how to choose the value of N

Comment: OK. So what is the sum on the right?

Comment: I think it's 2 but I'm not sure because of the variables, or at least it's smaller than 2

Comment: No, it's $1/2^{n-1}$ (it depends on $n$). So we should have $1/2^{n-1}<\epsilon$ i.e. $n-1> \log_2\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: Would it be correct to say $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$? I know how to evaluate infinite sequences but haven't done stuff like this before, thanks

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}} =\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k-n}} =\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}} =\frac{2}{2^{n}}$ where $j=k-n$.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help